# JasperReports Server: How to see What Port is is being used in XML

Tags: xml, spring, jasperserver

I'm using *JasperReports Server 5.0.1*

How do I detect what port is being used in a .xml file (WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml)

I want to do something like this (this is just to give you a idea of what I want)

```
<bean class="org.springframework.security.ui.cas.ServiceProperties"
          id="authenticationServiceProperties">
        <property name="service">
            <value>${IP_OR_URL} + ${PORT} + /jasperserver-pro/j_spring_cas_security</value>
        </property>
        <property name="sendRenew">
            <value>false</value>
        </property>
</bean>
```